# How would I make a set layout for a seat-booking application with a maximum of 20 seats per row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So how would I make a static layout for a seat-booking application with a maximum of 20 seats per row without changing the layout when resizing the window ? I'm working on a react project and I would like to have a variable amount of seats, but the seats layout can't change when resizing. This wouldn't make sense when trying to book a seat.

I gathered information that this is possible using grid and or flexbox. I've tried using flex-wrap but using flex-wrap changes the layout. Not using flex-wrap causes the seats to overflow to the side of the div.

The code looks something like this

```
<Section>

  <div>
    <Chair>
    <Chair>
   
  <div/>

  <div>
    <Chair>
    <Chair>
  
   <div/>

  <div>
    <Chair>
    <Chair>
  
   <div/>
<Section/>
```

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51zUC.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAZk3.png)

Hoping someone can give me a tip in the right direction.

I've tried using flexbox, grid, but none of them worked like I wanted them too. Gridbox gave me a good layout but broke when resizing. Flexbox hasn't helped much.

Comment: Here is a useful tool to help better understand flexbox https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Answer (score 1):

In order to make 20 seats per row without changing the layout when resizing the window, you can use a CSS grid. And then use **grid-template-columns** property to define how many columns that needed to occupy one row.
To demonstrate, I define 20 div elements in one parent element and then using **grid-template-columns** property I arranged 10 divs in to one row. For your case changed that value to 20.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  repeat(10, 1fr) ;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">10</div> 
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item">13</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item">16</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">17</div>
  <div class="grid-item">18</div>
  <div class="grid-item">19</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">20</div>
</div>
```